# Nodejs modules path for localhost

Tags: node.js, path

Im trying to changing path of modules. But modules not working in any path If I don't write like this:

`const io = require('C:/Users/User-1/node_modules/module_name')(server);`

It should run in `htdocs` folder, but its not working when I move modules and write new path.

`const io = require('node_modules/module_name')(server);` (not working)

What should I do for run node modules in `htdocs` folder?